# Решение задачи по двумерному массиву

Tags: javascript, node.js

Дан массив

```
matrix = [
 [0, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 5, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 3, 3]
]
```

Требуется написать функцию, которая принимает этот массив и складывает числа, НО если число стоит за нулём (смотреть по столбцам), то числа не складываются. Ответ к этому массиву 9.
P.S. т.е. смотрим массив по столбцам, первый элемент первое число 0, второй элемент первое число 0, третий элемент первое число 2, значит двойку никуда не складываем.
Смотрим след столбец и т.д.

Помогите решить пожалуйста, а ГЛАВНОЕ понять ход действий и как это решать.
То, что здесь перебор массива цикл в цикле я понимаю, но что дальше делать - НЕ понимаю. И написать надо не в тупую подогнав ответ, а этот массив из тестов может быть изменен, смысл не складывать число, если по столбцу оно стоит за нулём.

```
function getMatrixElementsSum(matrix) {
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
      
    }
  }
}
```

Это все на что меня хватило (facepalm)

Comment: А можно поподробнее объяснить как в ответе получается 9, не очень понятен алгоритм

Comment: @sasha-ld, все правильно. Числа, которые после 0 не суммируются

Comment: @sasha-ld Складываются числа, сверху вниз по столбцам, а потом складывается все вместе, но если число в столбце идёт после 0, то оно не складывается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала нам надо пройтись по каждому столбцу, т.е. `matrix[0][0, 1, 2, ...]`, а потом уже по каждому ряду. Т.е. первый цикл отвечает за прохождение по колонках, второй за прохождение по рядам.

```js
function getMatrixElementsSum(matrix) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
      if (matrix[j][i] === 0) break;
      sum += matrix[j][i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

const matrix = [
  [0, 1, 1, 2],
  [0, 5, 0, 0],
  [2, 0, 3, 3]
];

console.log(getMatrixElementsSum(matrix));
```

Comment: Я кажется понял, если я делаю matrix[i][j], то я бегу по строкам, а если [j][i], то по столбцам? значит внутренний цикл это столбцы

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @Stepback, нам надо узнать ширину матрицы. Т.е. она всегда прямокутная (либо квадрат), поэтому нет смысла смотреть остальные. Если бы была треугольной, то тогда был бы смысл.

Comment: @entihat благодарю!

Comment: пожалуйста......